# Why delegates defined in the class are not accessed by class object

Tags: c#, .net

I have got some BankAccount like below.

My question is using instance of BankAccount class, I can access the ActionDelegate delegate declared in the class but the not BalanceChangedEventHandler delegate defined in the class?

```
public class BankAccount
{
    public Action<int> ActionDelegate;

    public delegate void BalanceChangedEventHandler(object sender, BalanceChangedEventArgs args);

    public event BalanceChangedEventHandler BalanceChanged;
}
```

Comment: Please show sample which shows "can't access `BankAccount.BalanceChangedEventHandler`"

Comment: What do you mean with access? The fields are public so they are accessible

Comment: Is `BalanceChangedEventArgs` publically accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(emphasis mine)

> ... using **instance** of BankAccount class, I can access [...] but the not BalanceChangedEventHandler delegate defined in the class?

Delegate declarations don't have state. Thus, you don't access them through the instance, you access them like a nested class declaration:

```
 myBankAccount.BalanceChangedEventHandler // won't work
 BankAccount.BalanceChangedEventHandler   // works
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the delegate via the class name not an instance of this class

so you have to write

```
BankAccount.BalanceChangedEventHandler
```